# Why is this dictionary not saving data - C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have date going in to a text file, form the variable `nameSplit`. The following code is checking to see if the string that has come from the text file to nameSplit had previously been saved to the dictionary. If so, then it prints "Hoozah!", else it adds the data to the array and prints "Failure". However, if I enter the name "Jim" 5 times in to the text file, it just outputs `Failure", although it should have outputted "hoozah!" on the second entry. I'm not sure what is wrong!

```
while (!sR.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sR.ReadLine();
    string split = line.Split('$', ',')[1];
    string nameSplit = line.Split('.', ':')[1];

    Dictionary<string, decimal> names = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

    // inside the loop

    decimal n = Convert.ToDecimal(split);
    if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
    {
        names[nameSplit] += n;
        names.Add(nameSplit, n);
        Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!");
    }
    else
    {
        names.Add(nameSplit, n);
        Console.WriteLine("Failure");
    }




} sR.Close();
GC.Collect();
Thread.Sleep(66);
```

DATA:

1. Jim: $22.00, 2. Jim: $2100.00, 3. Jim: $6.00, 4. Jim: $32.00, 5. Jim: $2.00,

Comment: Did you forget to put the code ?

Comment: A good time to get to know the debugger. The bug is easy to find with it.

Comment: I've never used a debugger before :/ How does it work

Comment: And get rid of the `GC.Collect()` there at the end. You almost never need to deal directly with the garbage collector.

Comment: Done, thanks for that, sorry I'm kinda new to programming

Answer (score 7):

Define the dictionary outside of the loop.  Right now you are just creating a new dictionary on each loop and basically forgetting results from the previous loop.

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> names = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
while (!sR.EndOfStream)
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your data you actually need to split up the "entries" on each line and loop through them.  Assuming that there are multiple lines with a similar format you'll want to do the following.

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> names = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
while (!sR.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = sR.ReadLine();
    var entries = line.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach(var entry in entries)
    {       
        decimal amount = decimal.Parse(entry.Split('$')[1]);
        string nameSplit = entry.Split('.', ':')[1].Trim(); 

        if (names.ContainsKey(nameSplit))
        {
            names[nameSplit] += amount;
            Console.WriteLine("Hoozah!");
        }
        else
        {
            names.Add(nameSplit, amount);
            Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I renamed some variables and trimmed white space from the name, but the main thing is to split on the commas and iterate over each "entry".  I'm not sure why you are keeping a running sum of the dollar amounts, but you could use those after the loop.

Comment: I have done that, but it is still just printing failure

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse Are you sure the `nameSplit` values are the same?  Can you show us the input in your question?

Comment: What do you mean? sorry

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse Can you post the lines of data that the `sR` stream is reading, so we can see if there is an issue in the data?  For instance if one line is "blah:Jim" and another is "blah: Jim" they will not match because of the space.  We need to see the data you are processing to give you further help with your question.

Comment: Txt file is formatted as so `1. dddd: $21312.00, 2. dddd: $2131.00, 3. dddd: $21.00, 4. asdfddsdddddd: $3232.00, 5. sdfasdf: $21.00, `

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse you mention data that has "Jim" 5 times, can you post that data and the results.  Preferably in the question and not in a comment.

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse Just to be clear, does that data represent multiple lines or just one line?  If multiple, please make sure to format the data exactly.

Comment: It is 1 line, with just 5 entries

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse OK then that is your problem.  Your code is reading in that entire line and only looking at the first value.  I'll update my answer to show you how to deal with that.

Comment: But i am using this `string split = line.Split('$', ',')[1];
                    string nameSplit = line.Split('.', ':')[1];`

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse See my edit for how to split up the line.  The issue with your code is that `[1]` is only pulling one of the values that the split produces.

Comment: I see, however I am now receiving the following error:  Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse I had `decimal.Parse(line.Split('$')[1])` instead of `decimal.Parse(entry.Split('$')[1])`.  I've fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Lol, now this is occurring on the same line `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse OK just updated `var entries = line.Split(',');` to `var entries = line.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` to avoid the empty entry after the last comma.

Comment: @ETSTimeLapse Please note that there are a number of other places where variations in the input could cause exceptions.  It's best practice to add checks for these possibilities, but that's really outside the scope of this question.

Comment: This line `decimal amount = decimal.Parse(entry.Split('$')[1]);` is still causing two issues: Index was outside the bounds of the array. and Input string was not in a correct format. I have no idea on how to fix these as I am inexperienced in this area of coding.